# Nested attributes for best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-attributes, has-many

I have a model has nested attributes with another.

My question is: how better solution for call a build in controller or model?

See that model:

```
class ContentType < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :add_fields
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :field_content_types

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :field_content_types, reject_if: proc {|attributes| attributes['name'].blank?}

  private

  def add_fields
    self.field_content_types.build if new_record?
  end
end
```

Either remove `after_initialize` in model and add line in controller

```
class ContentTypesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @content_type = ContentType.new
    @content_type.field_content_types.build
  end
end
```

Have one reason to set build in controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are asking where you should build `field_content_types`, in this particular case, I don't think it matters whether you build it in model or controller.

The rule of thumb is to keep the controller *thin* and model *fat*, but the build method already so concise that you won't gain much from building it from model.

Personally, I would just build it in the controller.

Comment: Thanks @jason-kim! But in test the controller many mocks made, because `field_content_types` has many options too and are nested attributes. This is the correct?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. When you say many mocks are made, are you saying that you are building `field_content_types` with `if new_record?` Now if that's the case, I think it makes sense to write the method in model, because you don't want to repeat yourself writing `if` statement every time.